# For specific smooth surface S, prove that for every smooth vector field $\vec{F}$ on S, $\iint_{S} \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{S} = 0$

Tags: parametric, surface-integrals

A smooth surface *S* is parametrized by

$r(u,v) = \cos(2u)(2 + v\cos(u)) \vec{i} + \sin(2u)(2 + v\cos(u)) \vec{j} + v\sin(u) \vec{k}$

where $0 \le u \le 2 \pi, -1 \le v \le 1$.
Prove that for every smooth vector field $\vec{F}$ on *S*, $\iint_{S} \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{S} = 0$ (actually the original question is $\int_{S} \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{S} = 0$, but I think it's wrong since *S* has two dimension?)

My attempt is to calculate $r_u$, $r_v$, and $r_u \times r_v$

$r_u \times r_v = \{4\cos(2u)\sin(u) + 2v\cos(u)\cos(2u)\sin(u) - v\sin(2u) \} \vec{i} + \{v\cos(2u) + 4\sin(u)\sin(2u) + v\sin^2(2u) \} \vec{j} + \{ -4\cos(u)-2v\cos^2(u) \} \vec{k}$

and let $\vec{F} = P \vec{i} + Q \vec{j} + R \vec{k}$

then $$\iint_{S} \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{S} = $$ 
$$\int_{-1}^{1} \int_0^{2\pi} P\{4\cos(2u)\sin(u) + 2v\cos(u)\cos(2u)\sin(u) - v\sin(2u) \} + Q\{v\cos(2u) + 4\sin(u)\sin(2u) + v\sin^2(2u) \} + R\{ -4\cos(u)-2v\cos^2(u) \} \,du\,dv = $$
$$ \int_{-1}^{1} 0 \,dv = 0$$

However I don't know whether it is right way to do this question. Can anyone tell me? Thanks !

btw if there's a better way to do this, please tell me, thanks!

Comment: To answer your smaller question: mathematicians often use a single integral to denote an integral over *anything*. A double/triple/etc. integral is only used if you're teaching calculus beginners (because they usually feel more comfortable when the number of integrals equals the dimension of the domain of integration) or when you want to emphasize that you're computing an iterated integral (which is one way to integrate over $>1$-dimensional regions of $\mathbb{R}^n$, but not the only way).

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Thanks for your explanation so much!

Comment: I think we can just check that $\nabla \mathbf{\cdot} \vec{F}(\vec{r}) = 0 \ \forall \vec{r}$, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I read this question I started thinking: This cannot be. That's why I made a picture of *half* your surface. Looking at this picture you should be able to find out why all these flux integrals have the value $0$.

[image]

The essential point is that 
$${\bf r}(\pi+u,v)={\bf r}(u,-v)\qquad(0\leq u\leq\pi, \ -1\leq v\leq 1)\ .$$
This means that any any spacial surface element ${\rm d}S$ occurring in the total computation is covered twice by the parametrization, but with unit normals of opposite direction. The total flux will then be $=0$ for any velocity field ${\bf v}$ defined in a neighborhood of $S$.

Comment: Many thanks! Can I ask what software you use to draw this?

Comment: This was drawn by Mathematica.